# -fpic vs -fPIC powerpc confusion

Tags: c, powerpc

I am trying to reproduce an issue I am having with some simpler code. I wrote a small script to generate a C file that looks like this:

```
int SYM_0 = 0;
int SYM_1 = 1;
int SYM_2 = 2;
int SYM_3 = 3;
int SYM_4 = 4;
.
.
.
int SYM_16384 = 16384; 

int main() {
  int sum = 0;
  sum += SYM_0;
  sum += SYM_1;
  sum += SYM_2;
  sum += SYM_3;
  sum += SYM_4;
  .
  .
  .
  sum += SYM_16384;
  return sum;
}
```

So basically 16385 global vars. When I now compile this with -fpic, it compiles without error. When I compile with -fPIC however, I get:

```
/tmp/ccCB1pty.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccCB1pty.s:229412: Error: operand out of range (0x00008000 is not between 0xffff8000 and 0x00007fff)
```

I am confused because from what I read, -fPIC is supposed to allow the maximum amount of GOT entries with 16k entries per function, where as -fpic is 16k entries total. So, why do I get the error with fPIC instead of fpic?